# How to obtain DN values of Sentinel 1 Data (preferably GRD) given actual location coordinates using Python3 GDAL/rasterio/any_other_library?

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, sentinel-1

location of Svalbard

> 77.8750° N, 20.9752° E

I have sentinel-1 microwave data (in GRD FORMAT) downloaded from Copernicus. Each image is HH or HV polarized.

How do I calculate the DN value from the GeoTIFF image using **Python libraries only**?

Will I get multiple pixels in this process?

---

I could have opened the image in SNAP/QGIS and gone to the respective coordinates using mouse and noted down the DN value.

But, I have around 60 images and I'll get more. I'd like to automate this process.

---

I have found some relevant libraries:

- [Raster IO](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)
- [Affine](https://github.com/sgillies/affine)
- [GDAL](https://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#af9593cc241e7d140f5f3c4798a43a668)

I'm a CS guy and hence unfamiliar with the terminology.

---

Output of Gdalinfo:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: s1a-ew-grd-hh-20170924t192629-20170924t192733-018521-01f35e-001.tiff
Size is 10398, 10860
Coordinate System is `'
GCP Projection = 
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["unnamed",6378137,298.257223560493,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
GCP[  0]: Id=1, Info=
          (0,0) -> (13.2631076300387,-72.5486618031426,2186.18671441078)
GCP[  1]: Id=2, Info=
          (520,0) -> (13.7597223737679,-72.4374481358884,2186.19491506647)
GCP[  2]: Id=3, Info=
          (1040,0) -> (14.2502613555536,-72.3250085612605,2186.20325196814)
GCP[  3]: Id=4, Info=
          (1560,0) -> (14.7347738839402,-72.2113664687458,2186.21172482893)
GCP[  4]: Id=5, Info=
          (2080,0) -> (15.2133063720026,-72.0965461117854,2186.11678827554)
GCP[  5]: Id=6, Info=
          (2600,0) -> (15.6859225359963,-71.9805676769945,2186.11678873375)
GCP[  6]: Id=7, Info=
          (3120,0) -> (16.1526727532145,-71.8634545990536,2186.11678911932)
GCP[  7]: Id=8, Info=
          (3640,0) -> (16.6136141284617,-71.7452287225366,2186.11678944714)
GCP[  8]: Id=9, Info=
          (4160,0) -> (17.0688052189969,-71.6259115158689,2186.1167897312)
GCP[  9]: Id=10, Info=
          (4680,0) -> (17.5183058552513,-71.5055240780671,2186.11678997707)
GCP[ 10]: Id=11, Info=
          (5200,0) -> (17.9621769868422,-71.384087142167,2186.1167901922)
GCP[ 11]: Id=12, Info=
          (5720,0) -> (18.4004805479005,-71.2616210762379,2186.11679038405)
GCP[ 12]: Id=13, Info=
          (6240,0) -> (18.8332793346905,-71.1381458834231,2186.11679055449)
GCP[ 13]: Id=14, Info=
          (6760,0) -> (19.2606368895563,-71.0136812024448,2186.11679070536)
GCP[ 14]: Id=15, Info=
          (7280,0) -> (19.6826173874283,-70.888246309615,2186.1167908432)
GCP[ 15]: Id=16, Info=
          (7800,0) -> (20.0992855238857,-70.7618601227267,2186.11679096799)
GCP[ 16]: Id=17, Info=
          (8320,0) -> (20.5107064067509,-70.6345412063144,2186.11679107975)
GCP[ 17]: Id=18, Info=
          (8840,0) -> (20.9169454561719,-70.50630777672,2186.11679118499)
GCP[ 18]: Id=19, Info=
          (9360,0) -> (21.3180683209978,-70.3771777042252,2186.11679128092)
GCP[ 19]: Id=20, Info=
          (9880,0) -> (21.7141408218795,-70.2471685082238,2186.11679136753)
GCP[ 20]: Id=21, Info=
          (10397,0) -> (22.102986825391,-70.1170548059967,2186.11679145228)
GCP[ 21]: Id=22, Info=
          (0,507) -> (12.8978938221826,-72.4019314084178,2078.27829001099)
GCP[ 22]: Id=23, Info=
          (520,507) -> (13.3923949730691,-72.2916377112545,2078.28607762326)
GCP[ 23]: Id=24, Info=
          (1040,507) -> (13.880988550501,-72.1801102029003,2078.29399506748)
.....
GCP[481]: Id=482, Info=
          (9880,10859) -> (14.4768515859086,-67.2927673124267,-2.49035656452179e-06)
GCP[482]: Id=483, Info=
          (10397,10859) -> (14.8542219755154,-67.1786646643528,-2.41026282310486e-06)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2017:09:24 20:49:42
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=Sentinel-1A EW GRD MR L1
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Sentinel-1 IPF 002.84
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,10860.0)
Upper Right (10398.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (10398.0,10860.0)
Center      ( 5199.0, 5430.0)
Band 1 Block=10398x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: I would use rasterio - https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/190423/2856

Comment: @Luke Where can I find them? Using TiffDump or any other way?

Comment: GEOGCS["WGS_84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["unnamed",6378137,298.2572235604902,[AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

Comment: @Luke  I have removed some of the data as it was not accepting entire output

Comment: Do you want the pixel value at that location or multiple pixel values in the image? what is the ultimate goal? Are you a Mac user?

Comment: DN is not calibrated, so comparing values of multiple images is not very accurate. Consider applying calibration to the DN values first: https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/radiometric-calibration-of-level-1-products

Comment: @AndyB Yes. Thank you. I wanted to do this step by step. First pick out the DN values and then my next problem would be to calibrate and then pick out the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caveat, I have not tested this with a dataset that uses GCPs for georeferencing.  If this doesn't work with GCPs, you can use [`gdalwarp`](https://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) or [`rio warp`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#warp) to project the dataset.

It also assumes your coordinates are in the same coordinate reference system as your raster dataset (in this case, they should be as you are using longitude and latitude coordinates).

The below code uses the [`rasterio.DatasetReader.sample`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio._io.html#rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase.sample) method in Python to read values at the specified coordinates.  You could also use the [`rio sample`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#sample) command line tool.

```
import rasterio

raster = 'test_1band.tif' # 1 band raster
coords = ( #Lon, Lat / X, Y order
    (149.012,-33.7372),
    (149.554,-33.7031),
    (149.606,-33.9477),
    (149.498,-34.2445),
    (149.107,-34.063),
    (149.284,-33.9046),
    (149.373,-33.7753),
    (149.215,-33.8014),
    (148.997,-33.8916),
    (149.189,-34.0239)
)

with rasterio.open(raster) as raster:
    samples = raster.sample(coords)
    for sample in samples:
        print(sample[0])  # sample is a list, with 1 element per raster band
                          # if I'd sampled a 3 band raster, sample would be a 3 element list
```

For a window you would use a [Window/slice](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html) and an Affine transform (note completely untested):

```
with rasterio.open(raster) as raster:
    for coord in coords:
        # raster.transform is an Affine
        col, row = [int(round(cr)) for cr in ~raster.transform * coord]
        # 3x3 window
        win = ((row - 2, row + 2), (col - 2, col + 2))

        # read an ND numpy array
        nd_array = raster.read(window=win)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I like it that it extracts multiple bands also. Is there a way to open a small kernel of pixels around it? Or should I extend it using a loop?

Comment: @TarunMaganti see edit.

Comment: What do you mean by raster transform is an Affine?

Comment: That it is an instance of an Affine class https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/switch.html?highlight=afine#geotransforms

Comment: Thank you. I'll let you know on Monday. No way to access it now