# Get pixel values using rasterio.sample

Tags: raster, coordinates, rasterio, pixel, samplepoints

I would like to get the pixel values for a single point within a .tif file using rasterio. I have read several previous questions, and implemented the suggestions.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
with rasterio.open(filename) as src:
    x = (src.bounds.left + src.bounds.right) / 2.0
    y = (src.bounds.bottom + src.bounds.top) / 2.0

    val = src.sample((x, y))
    print(val)
```

output <generator object sample_gen at 0x7f290041f1d0>

How can I get the actual values, rather than the above output?

Here is the src.meta of the file I am using if this is at all useful:

{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': 999.0, 'width': 917, 'height': 871, 'count': 3, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32636), 'transform': Affine(80.0, 0.0, 248720.0,
0.0, -80.0, 4550640.0)}

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190423/getting-pixel-values-at-single-point-using-rasterio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `print(next(val))` works ?

`sample`outputs a generator, so you should iterate through it to actually get the value.
But be aware that once iterated, you cannot access your values back !
If you don't have a lot of values (here only one), you can convert your generator to a list.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, Remi.braun!

Comment: I tried print(next(val)) and got the following response

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pixel_value.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(next(val))
  File "/......./site-packages/rasterio/sample.py", line 40, in sample_gen
    for x, y in xy:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object

Comment: I will look into what a generator is, and maybe the issue will become clear to me? I am quite new to python. Cheers

Comment: I have found the solution, thanks for the help! 

I needed to implement the for loop:

for val in src.sample([(x, y)]): 
    print(val)

even though I only wanted a single value. 

I get the following output for my input .tif file:

[2.364684 0.       0.      ]

Comment: Sorry for not answering, I was sleeping ;) Glad you made it work!